# Binding data to combobox in WPF

Tags: wpf, binding, frameworks, combobox, entity

I am a beginner in programming, especially `WPF`. I have an application in `WPF`. I have changed connection to `.sdf` database from `Entity Framework` to `SqlCeCommand`. Unfortunatelly, before this I had the following code for binding a `ComboBox`.

```
<DockPanel Grid.Row="4">
    <Button x:Name="LoadButton" Height="20" ToolTip="Choose setting name to load"    Width="75" Padding="2,2,2,2" Margin="2,0,2,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Load Settings"  Command="{Binding LoadSettingsCommand}"/>

    <ComboBox x:Name="LoadSettingsComboBox" ToolTip="Choose setting name to load" ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=Settings/}" SelectedValue="{Binding LoadSettingName,  Mode=OneWayToSource}" SelectedValuePath="Name" Grid.Column="1" >
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
</DockPanel>
```

and:

```
List<Setting> _settings;
Settings = new CollectionView(_settings);
```

And it worked. After changing connection to `DataBase` there is no error, but `ComboBox` doesn't show any data. Before Setting class was generated by entity framework. Now, I made my own class Setting. What this class should implement? Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Vote this answer if you find it helpful.

As per my understanding if you are using Setting as data object you need to store it into ObservableCollection<>. Use like this :

```
private ObservableCollection<Settings> _settingList = new ObservableCollection<Settings>();
    public ObservableCollection<Settings> SettingList
    {
        get
        {
            return this._settingList;
        }
        set
        {
            if(value==null)
            return;
            this._settingList = value;
            //OnPropertyChanged(()=>this.SettingList); //It is not required as ObservableCollection<> itself notifies on collection changed.
        }
    }
```

If you are implementing your own Setting class then you should implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface to bind properties with combobox item. Below is the code for your reference:

```
public class SettingsModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotifyPropertyChanded event Implementation

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TProperty>> propertyExpression)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (null == handler)
            return;

        if (null != propertyExpression)
        {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(((MemberExpression)propertyExpression.Body).Member.Name);
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (null != PropertyChanged)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Above implementation gives you a method OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName). You need to call this method on "set" section of your each property in your class. Whenever property value gets changed it will notify to the DependencyProperty of control.

Hope this will help you.